# Number of discontinuity points of $x\mapsto f(g(x))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, continuity

Prove that $x\mapsto f(g(x))$ has only finite number of discontinuity points given that $f$ has finite number of continuity points and $g$ is continuous and monotone increasing (not necessarily strictly increasing).

I think this is true but I never see it anywhere. Just want to double-check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks true to me, assuming you meant to write that $ f $ has a finite number of *discontinuity* points.

Let $ S $ be the set of discontinuity points of $ f $ in that case and let $ T = g^{-1}(S) $.  Evidenty $ f \circ g $ is continuous on the compliment $ \mathbb{R} \backslash T $.  On the other hand, since $ g $ is non-decreasing, $ T $ is a finite disjoint union of isolated points and intervals corresponding to the finite number of points in $ S $.  $ f \circ g $ may be discontinuous at those isolated points and at the *boundaries* of the intervals (which is also a finite collection of points).  On the *interior* of the intervals we have $ g $ constant and hence $ f \circ g $ continuous at those points.  Thus we have shown $ f \circ g $ is continuous at all but at most a finite number of points.

Comment: In other words, if $f \circ g$ is discontinuous at $x$ then $x$ is either $\sup g^{-1}(y)$ or $\inf g^{-1}(y)$ for some $y$ where $f$ is discontinuous. So in fact it can only have at most twice as many points of discontinuity.